# Is there a way in winPE to continue booting from local hdd?

Tags: boot, windows-pe

In a lot of linux distro installers or livecd there is an option to continue booting from local or another media device without rebooting the system. I can not find anything like that for winpe 5.1.

My goal is to install winpe onto the harddrive and when the computer boots. It will boot into WinPe check some things and then continue booting into windows 8.

Right now i have boot into winpe checks stuff than sets the default os to windows 8 and reboots. Than when windows 8 is booted it sets the default os back to winpe. for when the next time the system is started it will boot into winpe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to "exit" WinPE to another operating system without a reboot because WinPE itself is an operating system. The installers and live CDs you mentioned do what you wish to accomplish at the boot loader level. Unfortunately the "set the other OS to default" routine you already have in place is the solution.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721977(v=ws.10).aspx